# Is there any package for achiveing esp-provisioning(wifi-provisioning) using React-Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I did check for packages that might help in achieving ***esp modules based wifi-provisioning*** using **React-Native** platform. Unfortunately I found nothing. I did find one that is under-development i.e: `react-native-esp-idf-provisioning` and not sure when the package will be ready. And I am not finding anything else as in for now so please if anyone knows how I can achieve the ***esp wifi-provisioning*** then that would be a great help.

Also I am not familiar with the native languages like `Kotlin` and `Swift` to achieve the same.(I did find some packages for achieving the same using these languages).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

We tried different alternatives like the one you mentioned, but they were either outdated and/or unmaintained.

So I just wrote and open-sourced a swift/kotlin bridge for react-native here, which we will be maintaining and using at my company.

https://github.com/orbital-systems/react-native-esp-idf-provisioning